# Placement of map function in nested ternary operators in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ternary-operator

Below is a nested ternary operator. How put `this.state.todos.map ((todo) =>` so that it works? I can simplify this somehow? At the moment I have an error: Unexpected token, expected ",".
If `edit` false, render first`li`. If `todo.date` ->`true` render first `li`, otherwise render the second`li` Someone will advise you? Can I apply such a structure?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      todos:[
          {name:'as', desc:'sd', date:'05-04-2008},{name:'sd', desc:'', date: ''}],
      edit: false
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.edit ?
          (
            <Form

            />
          )

          :

          {this.state.todos.map((todo) => { //problem here                       
            (<li>
                {  todo["date"] ?
                <div>
                    <span>
                        todo["name"])
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        todo["desc"])
                    </span>
                </div>

                :

                <div>
                    <span>
                        todo["name"])
                    </span>
                </div>  
                }
            </li>)
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `this.state = ...` line has syntax errors.

Comment: I correct this.state. There is still an error. Indicates the last `div`.Unexpected token, expected ','

Comment: There was a missing `)` in the above which I fixed in an edit to my answer below, probably you were using an earlier version...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  It's ok. Thanks. Why did you give me a negative vote for my question?

Comment: Sorry. But that is not fair. This question will certainly be useful to someone. It is very easy to make mistakes when nesting. It's easy to skip (), {}.

Comment: As I said, it's not my downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You're *already* in an expression context, so you don't want to use `{` prior to `this.state.todos` to enter an expression context.
2. Your `map` callback doesn't return a value, because you're using a function body (not a concise body) without `return`.

Fixing both:

```
render() {

  return (
    <div>
      { this.state.edit ?
        (
          <Form

          />
        )

        :
//      v---- *** no { here
        this.state.todos.map((todo) => // *** No { here
          (<li>
            {  todo.date ?
            <div>
                <span>
                    {todo.name}
                </span>
                <span>
                    {todo.desc}
                </span>
            </div>

            :

            <div>
                <span>
                    {todo.name}
                </span>
            </div>  
            }
          </li>)
        ) // *** Added missing ) here
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

I removed the `{` prior to `this.state.todos.map` and the `{` after the `=>` in the callback, and added in a missing `)` after `</li>)` to terminate the `map` callback. (The `{` didn't have corresponding `}`, so I didn't have to remove them.)

---

Side note: There is also a syntax error in your `this.state =` line in your constructor.

Comment: I added a comment for where the change was because I legitimately couldn't tell - I had to use a diff tool to find it.

Comment: @VLAZ - I removed it, because I've had trouble with comments in places like that. I'm trying to double-check now whether it would be valid, but there are other problems with the OP's code... :-|

Comment: OK, that's fair. When I first saw your answer there was no explanation for where the change was, so having it written in text is a good alternative. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @VLAZ - No bother at all, thank you for helping! I've fixed the further error and added the inline comments. Whatever problem I've had with those in the past, they're fine here, so... :-)